# Profiling user with categories

Tags: categories, user-registration, notifications

For a new website i'm looking for a profiling system for user registration.
I want to create a subscribe form where new users can choose their interest fron the categories created in Wordpress. This is the first step, the second is  to notifying the user about new articles just for the categories of interesting.
How can i create this system? I take a look also to crm plugin but seems not being this features.
Thanks to all

Comment: Hi Jhonny. You can add taxonomies to users in wordpress very easily. Justin Tadlock covers it in great (too much) detail [here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress). Then you can cuzomize the registration form to include the taxonomies, like [so](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)

Comment: my advice is don't try to recreate the wheel on this one, there are many existing post notification plugins available, some of which support post category subscriptions. once you have that backend side handled you could look at adding the field to the new user registration form.

Comment: @PedroCoitinho godo idea to use taxonomies (i never used it before so i have to study!) but What about the notification for user when a new content is published?

Comment: @majick Can You tell me any plugin with notification for categories or taxonomies? And how to add the selection in registration form to make it all automatic?

Comment: for future reference this site isn't really for plugin recommendations, but anyways, check out Subscribe2 or Post Notif.

Comment: I agree with @majick. The best thing about Wordpress is that you can speed up development with plugins. That being said, I have yet to find a good notification plugin (open to suggestions!). What do you mean by notifications? A jet-pack style dropbdown, e-mail, push notification...?

Comment: Thanks @majick for you comment, I still need a way to integrate in registration form the selection for subscribing to category (or taxonomy or any other system). Nobody never had this necessity?

Comment: @pedro coitinho from the client request are accepted email notification or push (iOS and android), to let the user come back on the website. But is required to select it in registration form

Comment: it may seem like a useful thing, but really unless you have a massive site publishing lots of stuff in lots of categories, it can just cut down on engagement... most would find sending a weekly digest notification is better. of course it can be done if you want to (set Subcribe2 category defaults and there is an add-on somewhere to allow logged in users to manage their category subscriptions onsite via shortcode.)